# SOAP UI displays faultstring even after error 500 is received. need to view the same in JAVA

Tags: java, soap, soapui

Here's the story:

Sending a request from SOAPUI (5.2.1) gives me either correct response or, in case of invalid parameters, the error in form of   xml.
Looking at SoapUI log this is what i see:

```
Wed Jan 18 16:32:39 EST 2017:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request

Wed Jan 18 16:32:39 EST 2017:DEBUG:Sending request: POST/XBC/services/TranslateGeometryService HTTP/1.1

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive for 10000 MILLISECONDS

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Target requested authentication

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Authorization challenge processed

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Authentication scope: BASIC 'Spring Security Application'@mywebservice:80

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:INFO:mywebservice:80 requires authentication with the realm 'Spring Security Application'

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Found credentials

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Attempt 2 to execute request

Wed Jan 18 16:32:48 EST 2017:DEBUG:Sending request: POST/XBC/services/TranslateGeometryService HTTP/1.1

Wed Jan 18 16:33:14 EST 2017:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Wed Jan 18 16:33:14 EST 2017:DEBUG:Connection shut down

Wed Jan 18 16:33:14 EST 2017:INFO:Got response for [TranslateGeometrySoap11.getLocationFromTramPoleTrackOffset:Request 1] in 35794ms (312 bytes)
```

(Note that those 312 bytes come after error 500 and connection shut down messages)

Response window, at the same time, in SOAPUI shows this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">Error: No Track exists with Track Code: CHS-CSK-UP-TW</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

This is perfect and works as i expect it to work.

Now for my problem that is seriously driving me mad. 
When i attempt to send exactly the same request from my java code that is supposed to return the error above, i receive IOException that says:
Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://mywebservice/XBC/services/TranslateGeometryService

So, pretty much same as what SOAPUI shows in its log.

But...

No matter what i do in my code i cannot get that message in faultstring that SOAPUI displays: "No Track exists with Track Code: CHS-CSK-UP-TW".

How is SOAPUI doing it after it receives error 500? Or, more importantly - how do i get it in JAVA after receiving error 500?

Tried playing with SoapFaultException class and SoapFault, but i could not find anything more anywhere.

Thanks to anyone who tries to answer this question.

Cheers,
Pierre

Comment: Show your code, pls?

Comment: Code is working fine Rao, as i communicate with web service in java without any problems. I just need to get to that faultstring when i receive IOException error 500 (like SOAPUI does) so that i can display that to my users instead of "error 500"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code in Java handler uses `SOAPMessageContext` TO detect SOAP fault and extract fault string from `SOAPBody`:

```
public bool handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context)
{
    try {
        if (context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().hasFault()) {
            SOAPFault fa = context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault();
            System.err.println(fa.getFaultCode());
            System.err.println(fa.getFaultString());
        }
        return true;
    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        System.err.println("Fault parsing Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Artem! I did not try SOAPMessageContext before. Will try it today and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Sorry mate, I just did not have time to dig deeper into the issue. Too many other things to do and management is ok for now to display error 500 to users instead of the meaningful message. I will have some time towards the end of this week and will definitely let you know if i find the solution. I can see the problem being that my response from which i have to get that meaningful message is coming as InputStreamReader. So i have to find the way to cast it into SOAPMessage first. Thanks again for following up. Cheers mate

Comment: Hi Artem, I've finally found some time to look at the issue and got it to work. Thanks for your help.